# wants to get fix the number of images from API

Tags: reactjs

i get images from flicker api but i want only 10 images except all how i can do this ??here is my code

```
loadimages(e)
{ e.preventDefault();
 this.setState({spinner:true});
 console.log('spinner');
 //  axios.get(`https://www.pexels.com/`).then(res=>{
 //    console.log(this.state.spinner);
//    this.setState({images:res.data,spinner:false});
//  });

axios.get("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne? 
tags=kitten&format=json&nojsoncallback=true") 
.then((response) => {
 console.log('hellodata',response.data.items);
 this.setState({
    images: response.data.items,
    spinner:false
 });
  console.log('images',this.state.images);

  }).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
 })


  }

  render() {
// const mappedStorage = this.state.images.map((item) => <li>{item.media.m} 
</li>);
//console.log('sds',mappedStorage);
 return (
  <div className="fun2">
    {this.state.spinner?
    <div>
       <MDSpinner  size={50}/>
    </div>
      :null}


          {this.state.images.map((items) => <img src={items.media.m} style= 
         {{maxWidth:'30vh',maxHeight:'70vh'}} />)} 


   <button onClick={this.loadimages}>
  Click Here
     </button>
```

im new in reactjs nd i dont know thwe syntx properly so u guys help me if u know thanks.....

Comment: Try `response.data.items.slice(0, 10)`

Comment: very nice <3 :p